# ASP.NET Simulate Postback in Windows Application

Tags: asp.net, forms, postback

I need to access information on a url which loads after filling its form and clicking on a button (postback). but I don't want to load page and fill the form and click that button programmatically, Is there a way to load a url with a header (or any other way ) containing those information (filled form and clicked on button) ?

Windows form or ASP.NET way solutions ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WebClient` for that. It can send a `NameValueCollection` of form fields and their values as a POST to an external url.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://www.post_url.nl", new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "form_input_name_1", "value_1" },
        { "form_input_name_2", "value_2" },
    });

    string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
}
```